# Many errors like: E/TextView(): Create typeface failed

Tags: android, typeface

Vodafone Smart Ultra 6 with android 5.0.2 has a lot of errors in a log like:

> E/TextView(): Create typeface failed.

Is it something wrong with android 5 or it's problem with this phone model?

For example, in my application almost any TextView creates such error (and I do not use custom font). The app works fine but a log is full with such errors.

Should I worry about it?

ADDED:[image]

Comment: are you sure you haven't used any typeface?

Comment: It seems there is no such log in source code of `TextView`

Comment: @shhp What do you mean by "log"?

Comment: Invoke method `Log.e("TextView", "Create typeface failed.")`

Comment: @shhp And where does it come from in such case?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Maybe the manufacturer modifies `TextView` or it comes from native code. But I don't think it is a big problem.

Comment: Can confirm the same problem on the same model